# can someone help with a latex presentaion on discord. (it will take 10 min max.) I cant figure out how the picture behaws

Tags: beamer, includegraphics

[image: I dont know why the picture is upside down and the title is overlaps]

Discord name: TrippyTtip#7526

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usetheme{berlin}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\title{Tracking im Internet} \author{Petros Kladis} \date{06.Juni.2020}

\begin{document}
    \frame{ \maketitle }
    \frame{\frametitle{Gliederung} 
    \tableofcontents }
        \section{Einleitung}
        \section{Cookies}
        \section{Was passiert mit unsere Data}
        \section{Wie kann ich es vermeiden}
            \frame{\frametitle{Warum habe ich das Thema ausgewählt?}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Big Data \newline
                \item Wie wird man getracked 
\newline
                \item Was kann damit machen  
\newline
                \item Online Sichercheit \newline
            \end{itemize} }
        \begin{figure}[h]
                \begin{center}
                    \includegraphics[scale=0.004]{Ry9pxSbg31iowAHP9QRWYS2p.jpg}
                    \caption{Glaubst immernoch es gibt Privatsphäre?}
                    \label{Abbildung}
                \end{center} 
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently, the `figure` environment is used outpide of a `frame`. Place it inside of a `frame` environment.

Comment: i did it but it still doesnt work

Comment: Could you please try with the `example-image` file instead of your image? To make it visible, you might have to use something like `\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}`. Is this image also upside down? If so, these is something in the code of your actual document that you did not include. If the example image is oriented correctly, your image file might be the problem. (Probably there is some sort of rotation information in the exif info of the image?)

Comment: There are many issues. Why don't you try to clean up, use `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`, drop `[h]` after `\begin{figure}`, drop `\usepackage{graphicx}`, and do as @leandriis suggests?

Comment: The exaple image is right side up and the title is also underneath. thanks ill use an other picture

Answer (score 1):

Is this the result you want?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usetheme{Berlin} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\title{Tracking im Internet} \author{Petros Kladis} \date{06.Juni.2020}

\begin{document}
    \frame{ \maketitle }
    \frame{\frametitle{Gliederung} \tableofcontents }
        \section{Einleitung}
        \section{Cookies}
        \section{Was passiert mit unsere Data}
        \section{Wie kann ich es vermeiden}
    \frame{\frametitle{Warum habe ich das Thema ausgewählt?}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Big Data \newline
            \item Wie wird man getracked \newline
            \item Was kann damit machen  \newline
            \item Online Sichercheit \newline
        \end{itemize} 
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}  % the original figure name: Ry9pxSbg31iowAHP9QRWYS2p.jpg
            \caption{Glaubst immernoch es gibt Privatsphäre?}
            \label{Abbildung}
            \end{center}
        \end{figure}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried it already but doesnt change anything, only the picture is lower now

Comment: The following works well (whether your jpg figure is too large or not?) ...  \end{itemize} 
        \begin{figure}[h]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}  % original name: Ry9pxSbg31iowAHP9QRWYS2p.jpg
            \caption{Glaubst immernoch es gibt Privatsphre?}
            \label{Abbildung}
        \end{figure}
        }

Comment: @SulinW Hi and welcome. Can you incorporate your latest comment(s) to your post to form a complete answer (starting from `\documentclass`)? You can edit your post by clicking the `edit` button.

Answer (score 0):

- Regarding your comments to @SulinW answer (+1), is not clear, what is your problem
- Where should be your picture?
- Testing your document example I cant reproduced showed image in your question. Caption is always underneath of image, however, since image is out of frame, it is wrong positioned.
- Considering comments of @leandriis and @Schrödinger's cat  your image is put on the middle of the last slide with caption underneath of the picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}% in real document delete "demo"
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usetheme{berlin}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\title{Tracking im Internet} \author{Petros Kladis} \date{06.Juni.2020}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
    \maketitle 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Gliederung}
    \tableofcontents 
\end{frame}
        \section{Einleitung}
        \section{Cookies}
        \section{Was passiert mit unsere Data}
        \section{Wie kann ich es vermeiden}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Warum habe ich das Thema ausgewählt?}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Big Data
        \item Wie wird man getracked
        \item Was kann damit machen
        \item Online Sichercheit \newline
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{Ry9pxSbg31iowAHP9QRWYS2p.jpg}
        \caption{Glaubst immernoch es gibt Privatsphäre?}
        \label{Abbildung}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```